# An 500 error after deploy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an issue with deploy on Heroku. Logs:

```
2014-05-25T11:19:04.968044+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=still-cliffs-5420.herokuapp.com request_id=6eb4091e-da77-463f-a294-f3f9dcb2fd02 fwd="78.8.138.68" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=91ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

No more logs.
I have a **pg** gem in my Gemifile.

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Main page does not work, but when i type **MAIN_PAGE_URL/service_operations** it works and i see the webpage.

Welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
autocomplete :owner, :imie

  def index
    @cars=Car.all
    @car = Car.new
  end

end
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: hard to help with the information you provide, please if you can paste the stack trace.

Comment: Could you post your controller?

Comment: No stack trace. Controller added in post.

Answer (score 0):

If an inner page works, it should mean your database association is working (a typical cause of this issue).

The problem will *likely* be something to do with the `welcome#index` controller action - typically that you have not performed **`heroku run rake db:migrate`** in your local console

--

The problem will *likely* be that you're trying to call database objects which exist in local development, but are yet to be created in `production`. To fix this, you either need to migrate your production database, or populate the db using **`heroku run rake db:seed`**

Comment: No problem. A tip - get the [LogEntries add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries). Run the "live" feed, and then refresh your app. It will show you the errors. Once you see them, post them here for me please